# Javascript: Setear valor por defecto usando DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, datetime, angular4

Usando JQuery dentro de Angular con el siguiente código:

```
$('#fecha_ingreso').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date('08/08/2012')
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text"
    class="form-control" 
    id="fecha_ingreso"
    formControlName="fecha_ingreso" 
    name="fecha_ingreso">
```

Y a pesar que el calendario se despliega sin ningún problema, no logro asignar esa fecha con el valor por defecto.

**[EDITO]**

URL de plugin: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

**[REPO]**
https://rickymuvel@bitbucket.org/rickymuvel/monitoreo.git

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: como dice el compañero @Marcos, pone el link de la libreria que estas usando para el datetimepicker

Comment: Mil disculpas, aquí está: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: Al parecer ninguno, en jsfiddle funciona bien https://jsfiddle.net/jL912pne/ Has añadido moment.js antes del plugin datetimepicker? jquery, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Estas ingresando mal el formato por defecto.

debe ser formato string de tipo: YYYY/MM/DD